# How do I pass a Ruby array to Javascript to make a line graph

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, graph

I am trying to make a webpage to display line graphs in my Ruby on Rails 2.3.14 application. I found a tool, called JS Charts, which allows me to create nice graphs using Javascript, but I am having trouble sending it the data it needs. Here is the way to make a static line graph:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myData = new Array([1, 395], [2, 244], [3, 223], [4, 210], [5, 238], [6, 223], [7, 275], [8, 31]);
  var myChart = new JSChart('chartcontainer', 'line');
  myChart.setDataArray(myData);
  myChart.draw();
</script>
```

I put that code into stats.html.erb, and it shows up. However, I need it to display line graph data that I provide it. A 2 dimensional array is created in the controller:

```
>> @a
=> [[1, 395], [2, 244], [3, 223], [4, 210], [5, 238], [6, 223], [7, 275], [8, 31]]
```

I should be able to use that variable in the view, and set `var myData` to it, with something like:

```
var myData = "<%= @a %>";
```

I tried other things like:

```
var myData = JSON.parse( "<%= @a.to_json %>" );
```

but nothing seems to work. Is there anything I can do?

EDIT:

There was an issue with the array the controller passed into the view (@a), which was empty. I was able to use:

```
var myData = JSON.parse( "<%= @a.to_json %>" );
```

to display the line graph with the right data being passed into the view.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure why your examples aren't working, assuming that you're in a .erb file and the ruby interpolation can work. Maybe try interpolating to a string? IE `<%= @.to_s %>`, because the javascript is going to evaluate what ruby injects into the script as though you had typed it in...

Comment: @eric paste the generated html of the result page.

Comment: Wait, somehow it worked this time. I think there was an issue with the data the controller passed into the view (`@a`). I used `JSON.parse( "<%= @a.to_json %>" );`. I appreciate the responses at least.

Answer (score 8):

Seem's like you got it working but you can clean things up a bit:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.myData = <%=raw @a.to_json %>;
<% end %>
```

or in rails 3 you can be super HTML5 savy and use the `data` helpers to add your data as an att of some html tag:

```
<%= content_tag "div", id: "myDiv", data: {stuff: @a} do %>
<!-- some html stuff...-->
<% end %>
```

and then in then in the javascript (with jQuery):

```
var myData = $('#myDiv').data("stuff")
```

and for the super keen, check out [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)