# ruby array serialization not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in my model:

```
def getFormattedAverages

   averages = Array.new();
   self.items.each do |i|

      x = self.responses.average(:x,:conditions=>['item_id = ?',i.id])
      if x.nil?
        x = 2000
      else
        x = x.to_i
      end
      y = self.responses.average(:y,:conditions=>['item_id = ?',i.id]).to_i
      if y.nil?
        y = "*"
      end
      averages.push([[x,y]])

    end

   return averages

end
```

In the view I have:

```
var dataseries = <%=@question.getFormattedAverages%>;
```

On my development machine, I get the data in exactly the form I need to pass into my graphing function.  It looks like this when I "view source" on the rendered page:

var dataseries = [[[31, 34]], [[45, 33]], [[34, 23]], [[10, 27]], [[21, 37]]];

But when I run it on my production server, it looks like this-

var dataseries = -6745-798571322000010791-2270-18;

Note that the x and y data on my development and production servers is different.  The point is that all of the brackets and commas are being stripped out.  Any help you can provide would be much appreciated - this one really has me stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407638/how-do-i-pass-a-ruby-array-to-javascript-to-make-a-line-graph).

Changing the code in my view to read

```
var dataseries = <%=raw @question.getFormattedAverages.to_json%>;
```

seems to work!